# Can't access htmlWebpackPlugin.files data from a template

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to access `htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css` from a Pug template and my build is failing since this is undefined.

I was hoping I'd be able to insert a `link` tag for each css file. Can anyone tell me why my pug template can't see the data, as described in the README (https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) ?

Here is the current contents of my webpack.config.js file:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = env => {
    return {
        mode: env.mode,
        entry: {
            vendor: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'jquery-validation', 'js-cookie', 'qtip2'],
            bundle: './src/scripts/bundle.js',
            global: './src/scripts/global.js',
            index: [
                './src/index.js',
                './src/scripts/branch.js'
            ],
            maincss: './src/scss/main.scss',
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
            filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
            chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js'
        },
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        devServer: {
            contentBase: './build'
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(['build']),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                path: 'build/Styles',
                filename: '[name]-[hash].css',
                chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].css'
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: false,
                title: "Home Page",
                filename: "home.html",
                chunks: ['vendor', 'bundle'],
                template: './src/templates/home.html'
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: false,
                title: "Branch Page",
                filename: "branch.html",
                chunks: ['vendor', 'bundle', 'branch'],
                template: './src/templates/branch.html'
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                // inject: false,
                filename: 'basket.html',
                template: 'src/basket.pug',
                chunks: ['vendor', 'bundle', 'maincss']
            })
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            options: {
                                name: 'Styles/[name]-[hash].css',
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.pug$/,
                    use: ['html-loader?attrs=false', 'pug-html-loader']
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the layout.pug file causing the error on build:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title I'm a title
    each css in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css
      link(href=css rel="stylesheet")
  body
    block header
      include includes/header
    block content
    block footer
    include includes/footer
    each js in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js
      script(src=js)
```

Comment: Sorry if it is a stupid question, but have you installed the pug-loader in your package.json? Because looking into your code above, that would be the only reason for not working. Everything looks fine! Another reason could be because you have defined as template the file src/basket.pug, but used layout.pug.